# How to use bail() in a validation chain with express-validator

Tags: node.js, express-validator

I want to bail before it reaches my custom validators.

```
   public classification = () => [
        param("id").exists({ checkNull: true }).isMongoId().bail(),
        param("id")
            .custom(checkIfSessionExists)
            .custom(checkIfSessionIsCompletedOrFailed)
            .custom(checkIfSessionHasExpired)
            .custom(checkIfSessionContainsFrontImage),
        validationResultHandler,
    ]
```

Why can i not apply `.bail()` here:  `param("id").exists({ checkNull: true }).isMongoId().bail(),`

Answer (score 3):

According to the express-validator documentation:

.bail() is useful to prevent a custom validator that touches a database or external API from running when you know it will fail. Can be used multiple times IN THE SAME validation chain if needed.

In your case it would be like:

```
[
  check('id')
   .exists({ checkNull: true }).bail()
   .isMongoId().bail()
   .custom(checkIfSessionExists).bail()
   .custom(checkIfSessionIsCompletedOrFailed).bail()
   .custom(checkIfSessionHasExpired).bail()
   .custom(checkIfSessionContainsFrontImage)
  ...
  ...
];
```

so, if some of this validation fail, the following validators will never run